# iOS CoreTextLabel for Html tags using UILabel outlet

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

I'm trying to use `CoreTextLabel` for HTML tags on my `UILabel`s, my question is how can I connect an outlet that is a `UILabel` with a `CoreTextLabel` which is `UIView` so I can do something like my `label.html = @"<i>italic string</I>"`

I tried something like this using something similar to what is described on [docs](https://github.com/appfarms/CoreTextLabel):

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"
#import "CoreTextLabel.h"
@implementation CustomLabel


- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CoreTextLabel* newLabel = [[CoreTextLabel alloc]init];
    newLabel.html=self.text;
    newLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:_overrideFontName size:self.font.pointSize];
    [self addSubview:newLabel];

}
```

My question is how can I connect a outlet `UILabel` as a `CoreTextLabel` and use all properties that `CoreTextLabel` provide?

Is there a better solution instead of using `CoreTextLabel`?

Comment: Why you don't use `UIView` outlet? Because `CoreTextLabel` is `UIView` and you can use it only as `UIView`.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem is that I have all my program with uilabels and I was looking for that could work with uilabel, like a category or something